# Edit profile picture on Instagram using Instagram API?

Tags: api, instagram, edit, profile

How can I edit my profile picture on Instagram using the Instagram API? I've reviewed the API documentation but haven't found anything. I'm using C# .NET, also downloaded ["InstaSharp"](http://instasharp.org/) but can't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python change instagram profile-picture with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501357/python-change-instagram-profile-picture-with-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current Instagram API (v1) this not possible. There are only 3 POST methods to modify data and those are for Relationships, Likes, and Comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.So i guess to edit user's data it's also not possible with current Instagram API (v1) right?

Comment: That's true. You can not modify anything other than relationships (follow/unfollow/block/unblock/approve/ignore) and likes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not committed to instasharp, this may have been asked and answered: [Instagram API using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594553/instagram-api-using-json-net)

The answer uses `json2csharp` (http://json2csharp.com/), but from there it looks like it would be a breeze to just set `User.profile_picture`.

Comment: Could you provide some sample `python3` code?