# Python change instagram profile-picture with requests

Tags: python, post, request, python-requests, instagram

I'm trying to change my Instagram profile picture with a python post request, but it does not change. I don't get any errors and in the response, it says that they changed it, but to a white Instagram person picture and not my chosen picture.

```
request url: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_change_profile_picture/

request headers: :authority: www.instagram.com
:method: POST
:path: /accounts/web_change_profile_picture/
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
content-length: 251409
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySbMgVbqkrGZYUfnE
cookie: ig_cb=1; mid={mid}; mcd=3; rur=ATN; ig_gdpr_signup=1; csrftoken={my_csrf}; shbid=9320; shbts=1543326033.1119306; ds_user_id={my_userid}; sessionid=3215216108%3A3qIcf1SYxlvIOd%3A29; urlgen="{my_urlgen}:7zHjeu:bVP01Os-2jGH6RETg-jCpkDsaRf"
origin: https://www.instagram.com
referer: https://www.instagram.com/{username}/
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
x-csrftoken: {my_csrf}
x-instagram-ajax: {my_ajax}
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest

Form data: 
profile_pic: (binary)

View Source form data:
------WebKitFormBoundarySbMgVbqkrGZYUfnE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_pic"; filename="profilepic.jpg"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarySbMgVbqkrGZYUfnE--

My code:
s.headers.update(headers_above)
img_payload = {
              "file": ("blo.jpg", open("D:\\{path_to_jpg_file}", "rb"), "image/jpeg")
                    }
img_url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_change_profile_picture/"
 r3 = s.post(img_url, files=img_payload)
```

Comment: Check if the fille isn't cached.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @PedroLobito If you mean the path to the image, then that's working, I have checked that with the PIL Image module. I think it's something wrong with the request, the problem is that I don't know what the problem is lol.

Comment: I'll try with mine and let you know the result.

Comment: "*How do I do that?*" - on FF,  hold down the
    Shift key and left-click the Reload
    button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. After sniffing the upload process via firefox developer tools, I copied
   all the `request headers` to the `headers`of `post request`, but it didn't work, then I removed
   `Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=-...XXXXX"` and boom!
2. I also updated the `"Content-Length"` value with
   `os.path.getsize("my_new_pp.jpg")`
3. Make sure you refresh the profile pic page with **no cache**, on FF, hold down the <kbd>Shift key</kbd> and <kbd>left-click</kbd> the <kbd>Reload
   button</kbd>.

I managed to change my profile pic on instagram using the following code:

```
import os
import requests

p_pic = "my_new_pp.jpg"
p_pic_s = os.path.getsize("my_new_pp.jpg")

headers = {
"Host": "www.instagram.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.9 Safari/537.36",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/pedro_lobito/",
"X-CSRFToken": "YOUR_X-CSRFToken",
"X-Instagram-AJAX": "YOUR_X-Instagram-AJAX",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
"Content-Length": str(p_pic_s), # should also work without this
"DNT": "1",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Cookie": "YOUR_COOKIE"
}

url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_change_profile_picture/"

files = {'profile_pic': open(p_pic,'rb')}
values = {"Content-Disposition": "form-data", "name": "profile_pic", "filename":"profilepic.jpg",
"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=values, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

---

**Response:**

```
{"changed_profile": true, "id": 233885295, "has_profile_pic": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.flis9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/09bb6c124303a825a67da0cb092c9ee7/5C8F561F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/44814766_1606677162811158_2721039563597283328_n.jpg", "profile_pic_url_hd": "https://instagram.flis9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/adb01e186d733d3660c300db5bae41a9/5C79DA67/t51.2885-19/s320x320/44814766_1606677162811158_2721039563597283328_n.jpg", "status": "ok"}
```

Answer (score 1):

0. **Acquire the information**

   After sniffing the upload process via firefox developer tools, I copied all of the `request headers` to the `headers`of `post request`, but it didn't work, then I removed `Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=-...XXXXX"` and boom!

   I also updated the

   ```js
   "Content-Length"
   ```

   value with

   ```py
   os.path.getsize("new_profile_picture.jpg")
   ```

   Ensure that you refresh https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/ with *no cache*. To ensure that the cache is not used, on Firefox, simultaneously hold down the keyboard's <kbd>[left shift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes#:%7E:text=Unassigned-,vk_lshift,-0xA0)</kbd> key, and
   <kbd>[left click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes#:%7E:text=Description-,vk_lbutton,-0x01)</kbd> Firefox's <kbd>Reload</kbd> button.

   To capture the necessary values, in your browser:

   0. Navigate to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/ with `firefox https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/`.
   1. Press <kbd>[F12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes#:%7E:text=F11%20key-,vk_f12,-0x7B)</kbd>.
   2. Select the Network tab.
   3. Select the XHR on the right-hand side.
   4. Change your profile picture manually.

      The relevant requests should appear if you search using the filter (search) bar for the values undermentioned.
1. **Add to code**

   ```py
   import os
   import requests

   p_pic = "my_new_pp.jpg"
   p_pic_s = os.path.getsize("my_new_pp.jpg")

   headers = {
       "Host": "www.instagram.com",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.9 Safari/537.36",
       "Accept": "*/*",
       "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
       "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
       "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/pedro_lobito/",
       "X-CSRFToken": "YOUR_X-CSRFToken",
       "X-Instagram-AJAX": "YOUR_X-Instagram-AJAX",
       "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
       "Content-Length": str(p_pic_s), # should also work without this
       "DNT": "1",
       "Connection": "keep-alive",
       "Text": "YOUR_COOKIE"
   }

   url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_change_profile_picture/"

   files = {'profile_pic': open(p_pic,'rb')}
   values = {"Content-Disposition": "form-data", "name": "profile_pic", "filename":"profilepic.jpg",
   "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}

   r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=values, headers=headers, timeout=10)
   print(r.text)
   ```

   The `X-CSRFToken` field can be filled using the data from `cookie csrftoken` field in the `set-cookie` field of the response header.
   The `X-Instagram-AJAX` field can be filled using the data from the field of the same name in the request header.

   The `Cookie` field can be filled using the method detailed at https://www.smartwriter.ai/university/how-to-access-your-instagram-cookie-and-what-exactly-does-a-cookie-do:

   0. Switch to the Storage tab.
   1. [Copy the cookie from the `sessionid` field.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yogeshwaran01/instagramy/master/samples/sessionid.gif)
      This method can also be used to extract the other information, and may even be preferable for the sake of simplicity.

   If your internet connection is slow, remove or replace `timeout=10` with a higher value. However, it is a failsafe to prevent the process hanging, so increasing the value is preferrable to removal.
2. **Response**

   ```js
   {"changed_profile": true, "id": 233885295, "has_profile_pic": true, "profile_pic_url": "https://instagram.flis9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/09bb6c124303a825a67da0cb092c9ee7/5C8F561F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/44814766_1606677162811158_2721039563597283328_n.jpg", "profile_pic_url_hd": "https://instagram.flis9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/adb01e186d733d3660c300db5bae41a9/5C79DA67/t51.2885-19/s320x320/44814766_1606677162811158_2721039563597283328_n.jpg", "status": "ok"}
   ```

You can find usage of this at https://web.archive.org/web/https://gitlab.com/rokejulianlockhart/RTBJK9/-/blob/main/code/account_manager/code/(account_manager).txt.py. The non-archived version shall include subsequent improvements not yet added to this answer.